# How to select number of elements from 2-D array based on given percentages in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Given an array such as:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

I'd like to be able to select *n* elements from the array based on a given percentage, and store them in a new variable *B*. If it returns a non-integer number of elements, I would like to round down (*ie. floor*). Therefore, regardless of what the last percentage is, it will choose the remaining elements.

Example:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] % array to choose from

B = [0.3 0.48 0.22] %  represents percentages in decimal form (summing to 1)

After evaluating the code, I'd like to have result:
C = [3 4 3] % note length(B) == length(C)
```

**Note:** Although 0.22*10 = 2.2, the preceding percentages only chose 3+4=7 of the 10 element array. Therefore, the last element of C will take

```
C(3) = length(A) - [ C(2) + C(1) ]
```

My attempt:

```
Given A and B,

for i = 1:length(B)
        if i == length(A) % if we're on last percentage, take whatever's left
            C(i) = length(A) - sum(%OTHER ELEMENTS%)
        end

        C(i) = floor(B(i)*length(A(1))); % select percentage elements (round down)

    end
```

I know this won't fully work, but I can't seem to figure out a way to make it work.

I apologize if this was confusing, I tried my best to explain. If you have any need for clarifications please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: I think the problem in your attempt is that `length(A(1))` should be `length(A)`. Also `%OTHER ELEMENTS%` can be replaced with `C(i:end-1)`. Otherwise, see my solution below for a vectorized (non-looping) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
C = floor(length(A)*B); 
C(end) = length(A)-sum(C(1:end-1));
```

**Explanation:**

The first line will get every element in `C` right, except possibly the last element. The second command fixes the last element of `C`.

**Example:**

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
>> B = [0.3 0.48 0.22];
>> C = floor(length(A)*B);
>> C(end) = length(A)-sum(C(1:end-1))

C =

 3     4     3
```

**Note:** Depending on the possible dimensions for `A`, you should be careful using `length(A)`, since `length(A) == max(size(A))`. Consider swapping `length(A)` for `size(A,2)`.